# JQM -navigate.url does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is my code -http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/203/.

I have created an page with id "`option2sub7`" and trying to navigate to that page through

`$.mobile.changePage("url"); [var url =#option2sub7"]`

But on navigation, the page is undefined.
[From Menu select Option2 in LeftDropdown and Sub7 in RightDropdown]

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$.mobile.changePage("url");` you indicate you want to change to page "url", not to the page whose name is specified by the variable url.
What you should call is `$.mobile.changePage(url);`